# Commit parent does not use previous commit ID

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

The commit parent does not use previous commit Id instead sets it to current commits parent. This creates a conflict while pushing merging.

Previous State:

```
1c4d3d7 **feature/epgw** origin/feature/epgw

commit 1c4d3d7
Parent: 5c2aecd 
Branches: feature/epgw, origin/feature/epgw
```

New State:

```
Made changes to checked out branch feature/epgw it created the commit id deb9302.

deb9302 **feature/epgw**

1c4d3d7 origin/feature/epgw

commit deb9302
Parent: 5c2aecd 
Branches: feature/epgw

commit 1c4d3d7
Parent: 5c2aecd 
Branches:  origin/feature/epgw
```

Why the parent for this commit is `5c2aecd` instead of the previous commit `1c4d3d7`?

Comment: What are you using to create and show these commits? A normal command-line `git commit` does not do that, but a command-line `git commit --amend` does do that (by design). You don't show what commands you used to achieve any of this, though.

Comment: I am using a team commit option from eclipse commit. Maybe from eclipse its is issuing an amend let me check. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you might want to add the [tag:eclipse] tag, then. (I don't use IDEs myself, I have no idea why the IDE is doing this.)

Comment: Thanks.. that was the problem . in eclipse there is a button to that marks it amend, I was mistakenly using it to get the last check in comments.

Comment: To get the last commit messages hit Ctrl+Space. EGit User Guide - Amending Commits: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Amending_Commits